# SFTP upload directories and files to a VM

Tags: bash, shell, scp, sftp

I have **2** directories and **4** files

```
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4096 Jun 30  2018 apache2 <<< 
drwx------  2 root root 4096 Jan 23 19:40 .ssh <<< 
drwx------ 10 root root 4096 Mar 12 03:08 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2832 Mar 12 03:08 bashrc_root.cfg
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 9702 Mar 12 03:08 bash_history.cfg
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  196 Mar 12 03:08 gitignore.cfg
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  725 Mar 12 03:08 env.cfg
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Mar 12 03:08 .
```

I'm trying to write the SFTP code to upload them into my VM, it doesn't seems to work correctly.

This is what I got as of now

```
DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S`
sftp john@45.88.88.57 <<EOF
    mkdir /backup/$mode/$HOSTNAME
    mkdir /backup/$mode/$HOSTNAME/$DATE
    put -r $path/* /backup/$mode/$HOSTNAME/$DATE
    ls -lrt /backup/$mode/$HOSTNAME/$DATE
    ls -lrt /backup | wc -l
    bye
EOF
```

I got a lot of these errors, I've already tried the `-r`

`put -r $path/* /backup/$mode/$HOSTNAME/$DATE`

```
job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Use cd .... or scp/rsync already :)

Comment: A small tip: use `mkdir -p` to create nested directories in one go.